# Using Inline-Block instead of Float for Gallery Layout

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery with image, title and description.

The image uses `float: left;` while the title and description stack to the right of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/aeuz0n8g/

I'm looking for a way to use `display: inline-block;` on the image instead of `float`, but the description will not stack under the title.

https://jsfiddle.net/5jbswg39/

```css
.item-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
}

.img-wrapper {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0.6em 1em 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.title {
  max-width: 275px;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.3em 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.description {
  max-width: 275px;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">Title</a>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Description description description description description description.
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: this is an explanation of why I'm looking to use `inline-block` instead of `float`.

For an unknown reason, when using my full site in **Chrome**, on **720p** resolution, the Title will overlap the Image.  But not in Firefox, IE or 1080p.

I'm only able to show a screenshot, since it's a local site being developed on my computer. But the JSFiddle link is the exact code being used. Though I cannot replicate the overlap in JSFiddle.

[image: overlap title]

I cannot debug the problem, because when I inspect element and touch *any* of the css, the titles reset back to normal, no longer overlapping. So I thought I would try alternative css to achieve the same layout and see if it removes the problem. I thought it might be a float rendering glitch with chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the title and text in a new element, set that to `inline-block` and contain it's width so it will fit on the same row.

```
.info {
  width: calc(100% - (50px + 1em));
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's a demo.

```css
.item-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
}

.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0.6em 1em 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 275px;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.3em 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.description {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 275px;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* added this */
.info {
  width: calc(100% - (50px + 1em));
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!-- Item 1 -->
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Item 2 -->
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Item 3 -->
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also make this a flex layout with the default `flex-direction: row` between the left/right sections, and a `flex-direction: column` for the title/text.

```css
.item-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
}

.img-wrapper {
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0.6em 1em 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.3em 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.description {
  max-width: 275px;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
}

.info {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!-- Item 1 -->
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Item 2 -->
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Item 3 -->
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="info">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to apply this to multiple divs in the gallery, I'll get back to you.

Comment: This worked and solved the overlapping issue. I used calc with inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using `display: flex` you could wrap the title and description in a div and do this.

```
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bt0p3FG.jpg" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description description description description description description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then

```
.item-container {
  display: flex;

  width: 300px;
  min-height: 90px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
}
```

You can optionally add `display: flex` to the `content-wrapper` class as well like this

```
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

FWIW I tested this on my MBP with the resolution changed and nothing overlapped for me.